# HTML Form - using action and onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I have a form which calls a javascript function. This function will only works when called from a certain page on my site (homepage). I am looking to put the form in the header of my website so that it can be populated from other pages, redirect to the homepage and then call the onsubmit function. Is there a way that I can accomplish this?

My html that I am using for the form at the moment is -

```
<form action="#" onSubmit="runRoute();return false;" id="routeForm">
        <input type="text" id="routeDistance" value="" placeholder="1" />
        <select id="routeUnit">
          <option value="miles">miles</option>
          <option value="Km">km</option>
        </select> 
        <input type="text" id="routeStart" value="" placeholder="postcode or location" />
        <input type="submit" value="plan my route" class="submit" />
    </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really make a lot of sense ... the only way to "redirect" from the browser is to make a trip back to the server, so if you're doing that, and passing along the form parameters, why not just process the form in that transaction?

Comment: You can't have the form _redirect_ **then** _submit_. A redirect will cause the state to be lost.

Comment: Perhaps you could have the form and its JavaScript function isolated in a single page which you could then embed in an iframe. Or, if you're using PHP, just use the `require` function.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll see what I can come up with.